# Pass state/hook/props from parent component to last child

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have started learning react from just 2 weeks before.

I have some doubt,

1. Can I create a shareable state/hook in react.meaning I initialize the state from parent class and can able to access from all the grant child class without passing ?
2. If the answer is NO for question one, then can I pass the state/hook/props from parent component and then can access from all the child component. for example, I have parent component `A`. I passed some value to child component like `<B someValue = {'someValue'}/>`. and the component `B` has three child componentes `C,D,E`. and the `D` component has another child component `F`. So can I access the prop `someValue` in my component `F` directly from `A`.

Thanks in advance.
any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

NOTE: I can achieve this through passing the value as props between each  component. I want to know whether is there any way to communicate **superParent** component and **grantChild** component.

Comment: This is what context is created for. You can find the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: ok. let me go through this

Comment: If you have any questions feel free to ask. Context can be a little annoying to grasp at first, but once you get the hang of it it works amazing.

Answer (score -1):

Passing data from parent component to childs you mentioned already like this;

```
Component A
   Component B
   Component C

Class A
<B data = {data}>
<C data = {data}>
```

But childs and components get nasty, it is really hard to handle these props and states passes.
@Lesleyvdp is already mentioned context. There are solutions about these confussions. You can use redux to store states or props on global that can be used any other child component or not.